# System.Printing in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-5

In the past I have used the PrintServer class in the System.Printing namespace. How am I able to retrieve the names of the print queues and print to them in .NET 5?

Comment: Target `net5.0-windows` rather than vanilla `net5.0`. [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop#usewpf

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jeroen and Hans for the assist! Here is what my solution was:

"* Starting in .NET 5, Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) projects should specify the .NET SDK (Microsoft.NET.Sdk) instead of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop. For these projects, setting TargetFramework to net5.0-windows and UseWPF or UseWindowsForms to true will automatically import the Windows desktop SDK. If your project targets .NET 5 or later and specifies the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK, you'll get build warning NETSDK1137."

I changed the TargetFramework and added the UseWPF elements you see below to my .csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then i was able to use my existing PrintServer and PrintQueuesCollection code